# CMake: Can't Compile C Library Dependency in C++ Project

Tags: cmake

I've got a C++ cmake project, call it P, which uses make on Linux. The P executable relies on 2 shared libraries, T and S. I want cmake to build the libraries if they're not already found.

Library T builds just fine, as it's a C++ Library. It builds before P as expected.

Library S is a C library. It does not build before P. When make gets to linking it complains it can't find S.

OBVIOUSLY BECAUSE IT DIDN'T MAKE S

Both T and S use their own build.cmake file that I call in CMakeLists.txt with include(). If I change S's build.cmake to CMakeLists.txt and build it, it'll create the library no problem. Then I can call P's CMakeLists.txt and the whole project will link correctly. Obviously I don't want the workflow to work that way though.

P's Represenative Code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(P pexec)
project(${P})
set(P_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
set(P_SRC_DIR ${P_DIR}/src)
set(P_INCLUDE_DIR ${P_DIR}/include)
set(T_PROGRAM_NAME T)
set(T_DIR ${P_DIR}/../Dependencies/T)
set(T_LIB_DIR ${P_DIR}/../Dependencies/T/lib)
set(S_PROGRAM_NAME S)
set(S_DIR ${P_DIR}/../Dependencies/S)
set(S_LIB_DIR ${S_DIR}/lib)
set(BSP_LIB_DIR ${S_DIR}/bsp/architecture/lib)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(${S_DIR}/build/build.cmake)
include(${T_DIR}/build/build.cmake)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR ${P_DIR}/../Tools/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR}/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR}/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PTH ${COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR})


set(T_INCLUDE_DIR ${P_DIR}/../Dependencies/T/include)
set(S_INCLUDE_DIR ${P_DIR}/../Dependencies/S/include)
set(BSP_INCLUDE_DIR ${P_DIR}/bsp/architecture/include)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${P_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${P_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE on)   
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

set(P_SRCS
  *source files*
)

add_executable(${P} ${P_SRCS})

target_include_directories(${P}
  PUBLIC ${P_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(
  ${P} 
  LINK_PUBLIC
  ${BSP_LIB_DIR}/libbsp.a
  ${S_LIB_DIR}/libS.so
  dl
  pthread
  ${T_LIB_DIR}/libT.so 
) 

set_target_properties(${P}
  PROPERTIES
  LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
  PREFIX ""
)
```

T's Code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(T_PROGRAM_NAME tbin)
set(T_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
set(T_INCLUDE_DIR ${T_DIR}/include)
set(T_SRC_DIR ${T_DIR}/src)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR ${T_DIR}/../../Tools/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR}/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR})

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${T_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE on)   
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -shared")

set(T_SRCS
  *source files*
)

set(T_INCLUDES
  *header files*
)

include_directories(${T_PROGRAM_NAME}
  PUBLIC ${T_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_library(${T_PROGRAM_NAME} SHARED ${T_SRCS} ${T_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(${T_PROGRAM_NAME} 
  pthread
)
```

S's Code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(S_PROGRAM_NAME sbin)
set(S_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
set(S_INCLUDE_DIR ${S_DIR}/include)
set(S_SRC_DIR ${S_DIR}/src)
set(BSP_LIB_DIR ${S_DIR}/bsp/architecture/lib)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR ${S_DIR}/../../Tools/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR}/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${COMPILER_TOOLS_DIR})

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${S_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE on)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-shared")

set(S_SRCS
  *source files*
)

set(S_INCLUDES
  *header files*
)

include_directories(${S_PROGRAM_NAME}
  PUBLIC 
  ${S_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${S_DIR}/bsp/architecture/include
)

add_library(${S_PROGRAM_NAME} SHARED ${S_SRCS} ${S_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(${S_PROGRAM_NAME} 
  ${BSP_LIB_DIR}/bsp.a
)

target_include_directories(${S_PROGRAM_NAME}
  PUBLIC 
  ${S_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${S_DIR}/bsp/architecture/include
)
```

Comment: Why are you linking directly against the so instead of `${T_PROGRAM_NAME}` and `${S_PROGRAM_NAME}`?  And unrelated, but 2.8 is an ancient version of cmake, so you may want to update.

Comment: Yep, linking the program names worked. Thanks, dood. Not sure why it worked for T? And not for S? The way I had it before but oh well

Answer (score 0):

Ended up needing to link to T_PROGRAM_NAME and S_PROGRAM_NAME rather than the .so files directly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).